# How can i increment a number in each line that has the same number

Tags: awk, sed

Example a file has

```
test test test test test
TEST: 15000
abcabc TEST: 15000 testtest test
TEST: 15000
test test  test 14000 test test test
TEST: 15000
TEST: 15000
```

it Must become so no matter the text when it see 15000 just increment 1 on each lines

```
test test test test test
TEST: 15001
abcabc TEST: 15002 testtest test
TEST: 15003
test test  test 14000 test test test
TEST: 15004
TEST: 15005
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{$2 += ++i}1' test.txt 
TEST: 15001
TEST: 15002
TEST: 15003
```

Increment `i` and add to to `$2`.

BTW, variable `i` doesn't exist when it is first incremented, so it is created with an initial value of `0` and then incremented to `1` **before** it is added to field 2.  If it were written as `i++` instead of `++i` then it would be incremented **after** the initial value (0) was added to $2.

If you want to only increment lines when $2 = 15000, then:

```
awk '$2 == 15000 {$2 += ++i}1' test.txt
```

---

or, with perl, using perl's `/e` regex modifier to evaluate the RHS of an s/// operator as a perl expression:

(I've added an extra line with `TEST: 15000.5` at the end of your sample input)

```
$ perl -p -e 's/\d+/$& == 15000 ? $& + ++$i : $&/eg' input.txt 
test test test test test
TEST: 15001
abcabc TEST: 15002 testtest test
TEST: 15003
test test  test 14000 test test test
TEST: 15004
TEST: 15005
TEST: 15006.5
```

In English: For any number found in a line, if that number is equal to 15000 then replace it with itself plus pre-incremented variable `$i`, otherwise replace it with itself.

As in awk, `$i` is created with an initial value of 0 (or the empty string if used as a string) if used when it doesn't exist.   BTW, this is a very common source of run-time errors when there are typos in a variable name (or when a variable is used outside of its scope), so perl has a `use strict` pragma to require all variables and other identifiers to be either fully-specified or **declared before they are used**. Use of an undeclared variable will then cause a compile-time error so it can be spotted and fixed before any damage is done by running the faulty program.  As this is just a simple one-liner and only one variable is used (and that only once), I'm not using `strict` here.

Alternatively, if there's any chance there might be numbers like `15000.5` in the input and you **don't** want them incremented by `++$i` too:

```
$ perl -p -e 's/(\d+)([^.])/($1 == 15000 ? $1 + ++$i : $1) . $2/eg' input.txt
test test test test test
TEST: 15001
abcabc TEST: 15002 testtest test
TEST: 15003
test test  test 14000 test test test
TEST: 15004
TEST: 15005
TEST: 15000.5
```

This version captures two patterns, a number (as $1) and whatever character (if any) follows the number (as $2) as long as that character isn't a decimal point (`.`). You should probably change this in a locale that uses a comma or something else.   On a successful match, the replacement is evaluated exactly the same as in the first perl version, but $2 is appended to it with perl's string concatenation operator (`.`).

Comment: Note that it affects spacing within the file (removes leading and trailing ones on each lines and compresses all sequences of blanks into one space).

Comment: seems it not work if there is lots of text in the lines

Comment: of course it won't work if your actual input file is nothing like the sample you provided.   your sample showed two fields, one word with a colon, and a number.

Comment: The question is updated more detailed now.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts to update

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
$ cat file
TEST: 15000
TEST: 15000
TEST: 15000 15000 -15000 015007 15000e-1 1.15000
OTHER: 1000 1000 1000
AND: 1000 1000 0x14999 14999
```

```
$ perl -pe 's{\d+}{$& + ++$c{$&}}ge' file
TEST: 15001
TEST: 15002
TEST: 15003 15004 -15005 15008 15006e-2 3.15007
OTHER: 1001 1002 1003
AND: 1004 1005 1x15000 15001
```

```
$ perl -pe 's{\d+}{$& + $c{$&}++}ge' file
TEST: 15000
TEST: 15001
TEST: 15002 15003 -15004 15007 15005e-1 2.15006
OTHER: 1000 1001 1002
AND: 1003 1004 0x14999 15000
```

It only processes sequences of decimal digits. So beware that it may not give you the expected result if there's anything but positive decimal integer numbers in the input, as demonstrated above.

Note that 015000 above is still considered as decimal (not octal) but not considered the same as 15000 as the comparison is lexical, not numerical. Replace `$c{$&}` with `$c{0+$&}` for the comparison to be numerical (via canonicalisation of the numbers used as keys of the `%c` associative array which remembers how much to increment each unique number).

If the aim is to make sure all numbers are distinct, note that it doesn't do that either. See how the first occurrence of 15000 is transformed to the same number as the second occurrence of 14999 above.

Also beware that numbers greater than 2<sup>64</sup> - 1 (18446744073709551615) will be represented with scientific notation (and lose precision). Add `-Mbignum` to work with arbitrarily large numbers, though you'd also need to force the conversion to bignum by inserting one in the operation:

```
$ perl -pe 's{\d+}{$& + ++$c{$&}}ge' <<< 99999999999999999999
1e+20
$ perl -Mbignum -pe 's{\d+}{0 + $& + ++$c{$&}}ge' <<< 99999999999999999999
100000000000000000000
```

Comment: I like that your code handles several numbers needing incrementation, and that you mention several caveats. But your code does not handle (the unspecified case of) incremented numbers colliding with numbers already present in the file.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity, yes and I give a hint at the problem by adding a 14999 in the input. In anycase, that's not a requirement of the OP (not that the OP's requirement are very clear, we're just guessing here as to what they want).